# Why does program hang on child to parent communication?

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe, fork

I am trying to understand why my program hangs. The Parent sends input froma 
 file it reads to the child program, and the child program will send the result of its computation back to it's parent. However, I have trouble sending the message back through a second pipe. The parent seems to hang when reading from the pipe.

From the other posts, I have read it seems to indicate that the parent should wait for the child to finish by using `wait` or `waitpid` (which in my case both of them does not resolve my issue).

I have notice by adding print statement that neither the PARENT or the CHILD finishes.. Could someone please explain to me why this is happening?

Why does this not work?

```
int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    char buffer[1];
    int i;

    int fd1[2]; int fd2[2];
    pipe(fd1); pipe(fd2);
    pid_t pid;

    // FIRST PROCESS.
    // -------------------
    pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0) {
        int cnt;

        dup2(fd1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(fd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            close(fd1[i]);
            close(fd2[i]);
        }

        while(read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer,  sizeof(buffer)) > 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "( %s )", buffer);
            cnt = cnt + *buffer - 48;
        }

        write(STDOUT_FILENO, &cnt, sizeof(cnt));
        exit(0);
    }


    // PARENT.
    // ------------------------
    int file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

    // READ THE FILE.
    while(read(file, buffer, 1) > 0) {
        if (48 <= *buffer && *buffer <= 57) {
            // PIPE TO CHILD.
            write(fd1[1], buffer, 1);
        } 
    }

    // WAIT FOR CHILD TO FINISH SENDING BACK.

    // int status = 0;
    // waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    // THIS BLOCK DOESN'T RESOLVE ANYTHING. IT HANGS AT WAIT OR WAITPID.

    // **** THIS IS THE PART WHERE IT DOESN'T WORK.
    while(read(fd2[0], buffer, 1) > 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "RESULT : %s", buffer);
    }

    // CLOSING PIPES
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        close(fd1[i]);
        close(fd2[i]);
    }

    close(file);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: How can you fit a *null-terminated* string in an array of only a single element?

Comment: And don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If by e.g. `48` you mean the ASCII encoded character `'0'` then use the character instead. You might also want to learn about the [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) function.

Comment: Lastly, don't forget that uninitialized local variables will have an *indeterminate* value (that can be seen as random or garbage).

Comment: Oh, another "lastly" thing: When you write `cnt` in the child, it will be the *raw binary* value you write, which might not contain any byte corresponding to printable characters at all.

Comment: Thanks! It was to my understanding that when the child terminates it sends `EOF`. Even when trying to manually print `EOF` from the child it still hangs. With regards to the indeterminate value, it should still be sending at least something back. The issue I am having is due to the "blockage".

Comment: EOF is sent when the write end of the pipe is closed. However, both the parent *and* the child have a write end. So it will stay open. You must explicitly close the unused ends of the pipe in the process which does not need them (or CLOEXEC, if you plan on using exec).

Comment: I have tried manually closing the STDIN/STDOUT in the child but the process  hangs right after the while loop, and the parent hangs at the read end of the pipe. They are both just hanging at the same time without anything happening. I can't pass it any new code. Plus, I did use `dup2` and close everything prior to that.

Comment: @DietrichEpp No!  EOF is not sent.  EOF is not a thing that can be sent.  When the end of the pipe is closed, an attempt to read that pipe will result in a value being returned, and that value is labeled "EOF" in some programming environments.  But it is an abstraction, not a thing that is sent.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: EOF is sent... this is just Wittgeinstein's ladder in play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't closing enough file descriptors in the parent soon enough.

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

The rule also applies if you duplicate the descriptors with either
[`dup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html)
or
[`fcntl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html)
with `F_DUPFD`

Now, your child process is following the RoT perfectly.  But the corollary for parent processes is that they need to close the unused ends of the pipe, and they must close the write end of a pipe that they use to signal EOF to the reading end of that pipe.  This is where your code fails.

Arguably, before reading the file, the parent process should close the read end of the pipe it uses to write to the child, and it should close the write end of the pipe it uses to read from the child.

Then, after reading the whole of the file, it should close the write end of the pipe to the child, before going into the 'read from child' loop.  That loop never terminates because the parent still has the write end of the pipe open, so there's a process that could (but won't) write to the pipe.

Also, since the child writes the bytes of an integer onto a pipe, the parent should read the bytes of an integer.  Using `char buffer[1];` with a `%s` format is pointless; you need a null terminator for the string, and a single char buffer can't hold both a null byte and any data.

Along with various other improvements (`'0'` instead of `48`, for example), you might end up with:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int fd1[2];
    int fd2[2];
    char buffer[1];

    pipe(fd1);
    pipe(fd2);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        int cnt = 0;

        dup2(fd1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(fd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            close(fd1[i]);
            close(fd2[i]);
        }

        while (read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "(%c)", buffer[0]);      // Changed
            cnt = cnt + buffer[0] - '0';
        }
        putc('\n', stderr);     // Aesthetics

        write(STDOUT_FILENO, &cnt, sizeof(cnt));
        exit(0);
    }

    int file = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (file < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file '%s' for reading\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    close(fd1[0]);      // Added
    close(fd2[1]);      // Added

    while (read(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0) {
        if ('0' <= buffer[0] && buffer[0] <= '9') {
            write(fd1[1], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        }
    }
    close(file);        // Moved
    close(fd1[1]);      // Added

    // Rewritten
    int result;
    while (read(fd2[0], &result, sizeof(result)) == sizeof(result)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "RESULT : %d\n", result);
    }

    close(fd2[0]);      // Added

    // Close loop removed

    return 0;
}
```

If that is stored in file `pipe71.c` and compiled, I get the following outputs when it is run:

```
$ ./pipe71 pipe71.c
(2)(0)(1)(2)(2)(2)(1)(1)(2)(0)(0)(2)(1)(0)(2)(2)(1)(0)(2)(1)(2)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(1)(0)(1)(1)(0)(2)(1)(0)(0)(0)(0)(9)(1)(1)(1)(1)(2)(0)(2)(0)(0)
RESULT : 49
$ ./pipe71 pipe71
(0)(0)(8)(0)(0)(2)(2)(0)(8)(1)(1)(5)(1)(1)(1)(1)(5)(1)(1)(1)(8)(5)(1)(9)(8)(5)(1)(1)(0)(4)(4)(4)(6)(0)(2)(8)(0)(0)(0)(2)(7)(1)(3)(8)(3)(0)(4)(3)(0)(4)(9)(0)(0)(0)(0)(7)(1)(9)(8)(1)(3)(0)
RESULT : 178
$
```